# TeamCity on same server as TFS?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am going to be responsible for implementing TeamCity into our development environment pretty soon. I have searched around and see no real answers, does anyone know if there is a 'best practice' when it comes to a build server. Is it Ok to install TeamCity on the same server as TFS, is it preferred? Or should I install it onto a dedicated server (which I can do).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that Microsoft's own [advice about TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx) would also be relevant here:

> You can host a build server on the same computer as your Team
>   Foundation Application-Tier Server, but, in most of these situations,
>   this build server should not host any build agents. Build agents place
>   heavy demands on the processor, which could significantly decrease the
>   performance of your application tier. In addition, you might want to
>   avoid running any build server components on the application tier
>   because installing Team Foundation Build Service increases the attack
>   surface on the computer.

So, you might see unnecessary slow downs on other operations like version control, work item tracking, etc.

Comment: I think that's a good enough reason to warrant it's own server. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Install it on its own server, you don't want it grinding tfs to a halt when it is performing a build.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the Teamcity server on the tfs server but if you can a separate machine, but as its the agents that do the work it those that definitely need to be on a different machine from teamcity and tfs if possible.